# How to enable communication of devices from different VLANs

Tags: vlan

In my router (DSR-1000AC with Firmware 3.11_WW), I created a new VLAN `192.168.3.x` following the instructions from [HOW to Setup Two VLANS ‑ DSR‑Series](https://eu.dlink.com/uk/en/support/faq/routers/wireless-routers/dsr-series/uk_dsr_series_how_to_setup_two_vlans).

I used a simple switch (not managed) and I connected it to port 4 of the router. Then, I connected a PC to this switch and it took successfully an IP from the new VLAN, the `192.168.3.2`.

Till here all good. However, this PC can't see the devices from the default VLAN `192.168.0.x` (e.g. a network disk). The ping doesn't return anything..

The above guide notes that:

> InterVLAN Routing can stay “Off” this way there is no way that both
>   networks will see each other

So I turned in `ON` that setting. However, the devices from the 2 subnets can't "talk" each other. So my question is how can enable that?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about consumer-grade devices (those for which the manufacturer does not offer optional, paid support) are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network, or on [su] for a personal network.

Answer (score 1):

An unmanaged switch isn't able to handle tagged VLAN frames correctly. It either forwards them as is (not compliant to 802.1D) or simply drops them (compliant to 802.1D).

Connecting a host to a non-compliant switch could work but it'd require the host to use tagged frames as well - you'll need to configure the NIC accordingly if possible. If the host can't tag the VLAN frames it'll simply be connected to the untagged/native VLAN. Configuring IP to something else than is used in the native VLAN will simply break IP connectivity because there's no consistent L2 connection.

Normal VLAN operation uses tagged frames on VLAN trunks (between router and switch) and single-VLAN, untagged frames on host/access ports. This requires proper configuration on the managed switch.

Answer (score 0):

If you configured the router port to be untagged (which it seems you have since the PC pulled an IP from the right subnet and the guide tells you to mark it's PVID as the new VLAN as well) then connecting it regular unmanaged switch should not be an issue. You should be able ping the neighboring VLANs gateway IP, as long as that router allows ICMP to those interfaces. I suspect your issue is actually having to do with broadcast domains. If you are using a protocol like SMB (i.e. Windows shares), PCs will not show up from the other VLAN when browsing for them. SMB and many other "sharing" protocols use broadcasting to find one another. The point of using different VLANs is to separate broadcast domains, so they will not be able to 'see' each other. You should still be able to browse to the other devices though by putting in their IP directly.